# How do I find the radius of convergence of these power series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Please help me find the radius of convergence of the following power series including the method of solving them.

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^{n!}x^{n!}\tag{1}$$

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n^2}{2^n}x^{n^2}\tag{2}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Do you have thoughts on the problems that you can share so we can better respond? If this is HW, it should be tagged as such. Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The formula for the convergence radius of a power series is $$\frac 1 R= \limsup_{n \to \infty} |a_n|^{1/n}.$$
 In the first case $a_k =0$ if $ k \neq n!$ and $a_k =2^k$ if $k=n!$. Thus $$\frac 1 R=\lim_{k \to \infty} (2^k)^{1/k}=2.$$
 In the second case $a_k=0$ if $k \neq n^2$ and $a_k=\frac k {2^\sqrt{k}}$ if $k=n^2$. Thus $$\frac 1 R=\lim_{k \to \infty }\left(\frac k {2^{\sqrt{k}}}\right)^{1/k}= \frac {\lim_{k \to \infty} k^{1/k}} {\lim_{k \to \infty} \left(2^{\sqrt{k}}\right)^{1/k}}=\frac 1 {\lim_{k \to \infty} 2^{k^{-1/2}}}=\frac 1 {2^{\lim_{k \to \infty} (k^{-1/2})}}=1.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** For the first series see this

$$ |x^{n!}| \leq |x^n|,  \quad |x|<1 $$

Comment: What i got was R=0 by taking the limit of the nth root of 2^(n!)

Comment: Is there any formal way of solving such questions that have x terms with powers other than n (Like n!,n^2) conventionally what we see is power series with x^n

Comment: What I gave you is what's called the comparison test. since $\sum_{n} |2x|^n$ is geometric series converges for $|2x|<1 \implies |x|<1/2$. You can do the same with the other one.